# function Now() in ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba7

I can't figure it out why macro everytime save file with filename  .xl&somedigits like filename.xl105 with this code:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\" & "Fname " & Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY" & ".xlsm")), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

like (from  ".xlsm") sm was some part of a function. The resulting filenames looks like Fname.xl105, Fname.xl35, Fname.xl254 etc... Some thougts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ".xlsm" is inside the `Format`.

`Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY" & ".xlsm")` returns **06.05.2021.xl105**
`Format(now(),"xlsm")` returns **xl355**

I'm guessing it's using xlsm as symbols - the `m` represents the month (so it's returning 5 in May).

Use

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\" & "Fname " & Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY") & ".xlsm"), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Also, `Fname` looks like a variable but you're using it as a string.  Maybe use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\" & Fname  & Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY") & ".xlsm"), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```